# C# SQL Server command data type mismatch

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to insert record to student table and I used a `SqlCommand` but when executing command as shown here, a datatype mismatch error occurs.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("insert into Student(studentID,studentName,birthDate) values(" + studentID.Text + ",'" + studentName.Text +"','" + birthDate.Text + "')", con);
```

Comment: Do not concatenate string to create sql commands. Use parameters, and specify for each parameter the datatype to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use parameters to solve this problem like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Student(studentID, studentName, birthDate) values(@studentID, @studentName, @birthDate)" , con);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentID", studentID.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentName", studentName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birthDate", birthDate.Text);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: I bet that this will fail with the same exact error message

Comment: try it then decide

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: Actually, not just *you can use parameters* - you ***SHOULD ALWAYS*** use parameters. It avoids so many troubles like SQL injection vulnerabilities and a lot of issues with data types, too .